# Cancel http requests running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, httprequest

I create multi requests with `NSURLSession`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_urls count]; i++) {
...
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable errorr) {
...
    }] resume];
}
```

How to kill all the running tasks ?

Comment: you are using alamofire for request?

Comment: @jignesh Vadadoriya No

Comment: @user1568204 : call `invalidateAndCancel` on session to cancel all outstanding tasks read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411538-invalidateandcancel